# How do I add information to existing simple products by CSV?

Tags: import, export, importexport, page-content

My company is trying to add UPC information in bulk to our existing Magento products. We think that scanning our SKU's in a CSV and then scanning the UPC information would be very efficient for us.

Does anyone know how to add this information by SKU with a CSVfile? Or would a script need to be written?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the build in Import/Export feature (not Dataflow!) for that. Create a CSV file with 1 column for the SKU (add "sku" in the header line) and one line for each attribute you want to import. Put the attribute code of the attribute into the header line.
Please find a full explanation of the import CSV format at https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/. But, if you only want to update attributes of existing products, it's as simple as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution in my opinion is a free program called Magmi.  It can be downloaded here http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/, but requires a little knowledge to setup and figure out.  Once it is though, it's very easy and fast to do exactly what you're saying.  There is also a wiki link on that page to get started.

You can also use the built in Dataflow feature of Magento, but again, in my opinion it is a little more touchy to work with.

Comment: and just to add (as you'll see when you research Magmi, you can pretty much load any data your store needs via Magmi. Not just SKU updates, but all related data, images etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've downloaded it and ran into the No File error that's being caused by the way it's being cached.

How might one go about setting that up with the dataflow feature?

Comment: Honestly, I'd really use dataflow as a last resort.  Please describe your magmi error in more detail.  FYI, for my magmi installation, I actually put it on a subdomain because it was killing my magento admin session.  Putting on its own subdomain corrected it.    

You have to install magmi, and then upload your file to the var import folder.  Then select it and run from magmi.  Also, please accept my originial answer if it works for you.

Comment: Don't use dataflow, use ImportExport instead. See my answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24756/what-is-the-difference-between-import-export-vs-dataflow.