# Why is my csv file not importing successfully in the Dataflow Profile even when it was verified as valid in Check Data?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, csv, magmi

Hi I am trying to create simple products and a configurable product, then associate those simple products to the configurable product using one csv file. I went to System > Import/Export > Import and Check Data of this file. I got this result:

*Checked rows: 9, checked entities: 4, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0
File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button*
[image: Check Data and Dataflow import results]

I went ahead and import the file and it was successful but the products are not showing in my catalog. I then tried importing in Dataflow-Profiles but when imported, I got several errors saying:

*Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.*

Can anyone help me figure out why that error keeps on appearing? How can I import successfully? Please click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42mp1val8jb0kto/victorinoximportsample7.csv?dl=0) to download the file that I am trying to import. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Please check you csv file by opening it in some editor like notepad++ and see whether sku header is enclosed in double quotes or not? use open office calc to prepare the csv file and try again once more.

Comment: What makes you think that the products do not show up in the catalog? Did you check the _Catalog → Manage Products_ grid with all filters reset? Dataflow is a completely different story using a different structure, you cannot import Import/Export CSV files there.

Comment: @Muk - Thank you for your comment! The sku header is not enclosed with double quotes. should it be enclosed?

Comment: @mam08ixo - Thank you for your comment! Yes, I checked the Catalog → Manage Products grid with all filters reset and the items I imported are not there. Do you mean, I can't import from Dataflow?

Comment: What I meant is that an import file valid for `Mage_ImportExport` will not work with `Mage_Dataflow` because they use different CSV structures. Did you get that _Import successfully done._ message when using _Import/Export → Import_?

Comment: @kristine Can you copy paste a few lines of your csv import files in the question?

Comment: You shouldn't be using Dataflow at all - it's extremely slow and deprecated since Magento 1.5 (CE). You can use ImportExport which is dataflow's replacement instead. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24756/what-is-the-difference-between-import-export-vs-dataflow where I answered that in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Please check and make sure that you don't have extra carriage returns/line feeds on the end of your csv file.  Open the file, and delete any blank lines/rows.

Often times, when you export from Excel, it will add extra rows to the export that are nothing more than blank lines.