# Store product export csv file in var/importexport folder

Tags: magento-1.8, export, importexport

I want to store the product export csv file on a folder while generating from the admin panel.

Right now its only directly downloadable from the admin panel, but I want to store that file in a particular folder like "var/importexport".

Please advise.

Comment: You can use dataflow profiles, this will only save the export files in FTP, probably at 'var/export/' folder.

Comment: Don't use dataflow, see my answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24756/what-is-the-difference-between-import-export-vs-dataflow.

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController::exportAction (of course don't change the file directly, but overwrite the controller update safe).

Change this part:

```
            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                $model->getContentType()
            );
```

to:

```
            $filename = $model->getFileName();
            $content = $model->export();
            file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'importexport' . DS . $filename, $content);
            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                $filename,
                $content,
                $model->getContentType()
            );
```

This should save the file in the given directory. Of course you can modify the filename `$filename` at that point.